# Dll file is missing in my Debug folder (C#-Selenium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, nunit

I am trying to run my Automated test cases from the command line.

My tests were written in C# - NUnit-Selenium-Webdriver. I opened my solution in file explorer then navigated to Bin--> Debug, but I am not able to find my Test.dll file .I am new to NUnit (I was doing automation using java previously)

I feel I have missed the some installation process somewhere but I am not sure what I missed. I tried different versions of NUnit also. I read the official documentation also but still I am not able to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use NUnit.ConsoleRunner, you can find it in your solution packages folder or in the directory if you have already installed in separetly.

First find the NUnit.ConsoleRunner, hold shift down and right click the exe and click the Copy as Path, open command line and paste the path there, dont close it.

Second part is to find the dll of the test, that would be in the project directory in the bind/debug, the dll would be named just like the project name.If you cant see the dll, build your project and look for it in the bin/debug directory again.After you find the dll take the path just like you did with the Nuni.ConsoleRunner. In the command line where you already paste the path of the NUnit.ConsoleRunner put a space after the path and paste the dll path and hit enter.